# Why is Axios returning data as "undefined" from the API when using React using Vite?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using Axios to fetch data related to movies as part of my project. However, when I execute console.log(response.data), it returns something in the form of an HTML document. When I visit the link directly, it yields data in JSON format. How do I fix this ?

**1)The main code:**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './Banner.css' 
import requests from './Requests';
import axios from './Axios'

function Banner() {

    const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let fetchData = async () => {
            let response = await axios.get(requests.fetchPopular);
            console.log(response.data);

        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);`
```

**2)Axios.jsx code:**

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
     baseURL: "​https://api.themoviedb.org/3"
});

export default instance`
```

**Requests.jsx code:**

```
const API_KEY = "**************************";
const requests = {
    fetchPopular: `​​/movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}`
};
export default requests;
```

**Output of console.log(response.data):**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="module">
import RefreshRuntime from "/@react-refresh"
RefreshRuntime.injectIntoGlobalHook(window)
window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {}
window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type
window.__vite_plugin_react_preamble_installed__ = true
</script>

    <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx?t=1709691322963"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**I was trying to retrieve data using Axios in object form however, I'm receiving it as "undefined" even though when I visit the link directly, the API seems to be working.**

Comment: Ahh, you seem to have some garbage characters in `"​https://api.themoviedb.org/3"` between `"` and `h`

Comment: It's a zero-width space, so your code is probably NOT reaching the api at all, but making a request of your server

Comment: are you sure the response has the `data` property? try to `console.log(response)` instead to see what is that

Answer (score 0):

`headers: {accept: 'application/json'}`, you have to set headers for request. You can refer to the API docs [here](https://developer.themoviedb.org/reference/movie-popular-list)

For Axios the headers should be

```
headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
```